# navigateToSObject is not defined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to figure out why `navigateToSObject` is coming back undefined. I'm new to Lightning so I'm sure it is something simple I'm missing.

The debug showed `$A` returning `SecureAura: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }`

I'm calling the method from the component here:

`<button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.gotoContact}">Go To Contact</button>`

```
}, 
gotoContact: function(cmp, event, helper) {     
    var action = cmp.get('c.getContact'); 
    action.setParams({ guid : cmp.get("v.guid") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state == "SUCCESS") {
            var sobjectEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            sObjectEvent.setParams({
                "recordId": response.getReturnValue(),
                "slideDevName": "detail"
            });
            sObjectEvent.fire();                    
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);       
},
```

Comment: Please include an exact copy of the error message text you are getting.

Comment: @Keith C error is `ReferenceError: Error in $A.getCallback() [sObjectEvent is not defined]
Callback failed: apex://SSOViewOverrideController/ACTION$getContact`

Comment: The docs say "This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.". Are you using one of those?

Comment: You seem to be using *sObjectEvent* outside the scope where it is defined. You have defined it within the if block, whereas you are using it outside that block.

Comment: I am using this in Lightning Experience interface. Yes, I had sObjectEvent placed outside of the if block, but even within the if block it still comes back undefined.

Comment: And this time, it's case sensitive. You need to change *var sobjectEvent* to *var sObjectEvent* (notice the upper O).

Comment: @JayantDas great catch, JS is case sensitive.so variable names should be proper.

Comment: @JayantDas, that was it...thank you. I'm not used to JS and the case sensitivity. I needed the second pair of eyes on it! Thank you!!

Comment: This is difficult to catch, have been into such situation, so was carefully reviewing it, and glad that was the problem :). I have rolled up the comments as an answer, just in case if it helps someone further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolling up comment as answer:

As per your original post, you had declared the event variable within the if block and you were using it outside the scope and thus you were getting undefined variable error.

```
if(state == "SUCCESS") {
        var sobjectEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject"); // declared here
        sObjectEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": response.getReturnValue(),
            "slideDevName": "detail"
        });

    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);     
sObjectEvent.fire();  // used here and thus error
```

Later when you moved it to the if block, it was case sensitivity which was not working.

```
if(state == "SUCCESS") {
        var sobjectEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        sObjectEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": response.getReturnValue(),
            "slideDevName": "detail"
        });
        sObjectEvent.fire(); // it was case sensitivity this time, declaration needed to be changed to sObjectEvent (notice the upper O)                   
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Finally, changing the variable name to **sObjectEvent** and using it within the block where declared resolved the issue.

Comment: I would also add, "don't use long variable names where they are not needed"; less chance of typo problems using e.g. `var e = $A.get(...`.

Comment: I would say it's more dependent on individual's style. I kind of like to use more *relevant* names for variables. I would have possibly used *navEvt* here which resembles it's a navigation event.

Comment: My point is that long names in case-sensitive and non-compiled JavaScript are prone to typos whereas short names are not. In short fragments of code the context - what the `e` represents - is clear and doesn't need to be expressed in a long variable name. But agree its a matter of company/individual style.